# Debug approach for driver code having sleep call in Interrupt service routine

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I was asked this as one of interview question on how I will debug/debug methodologies you will apply if you encounter an unknown driver code where sleep call/kernel API that can sleep is executed inside Interrupt service routine ? In what states kernel will go if sleep function is executed ?

Note: I am aware that we should not put/call any sleep functions inside Interrupt routine but this question is more on what debug approach will be incase such code comes in real-time execution.

Comment: Kernel will crash because of wrong returned stack or due to sleep in between irs deadlock occurs

Comment: Kernel **won't** crash. Once your sleep routine is executed in interrupt handler you will see next message in your kernel log (in `dmesg` output): `BUG: Scheduling while atomic`. So you can just search in kernel log for this line.